# Google Apps Script/ Google Sheets - Only copy IF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Updated the question; hope this is enough info. Please say if there is anything else needed to answer this question! I am new here, but I am more than happy to learn!

I am looking for a way to tell cells GN4:GN to only copy from cells in GM4:GM if they contain "PASS", "UNCERTAIN", or "REJECT"; if not, nothing should be done. It is important that if the cells in GM4:GM contain something else than the listed words, GN4:GN stay the same as before.

So I have got two sheets:

Sheet 1 is the dashboard, in cell B3 you can enter an email adress (that belongs to a candidate) and through vlookup you can see all the relevant data for this email adress. Now, you want to make a decision based on the data you see and it would be nice if that decision could be made on the present sheet. I created a dropdown menu with 'PASS', 'UNCERTAIN', and 'REJECT'.

Sheet 2 is the data sheet. Here, the decision made in sheet 1 should be saved --> to the correct e-mail adress (or row).

To solve this I made two columns GM & GN. GM contains the follwing:

```
=IF($A4=Sheet1!$B$3;VLOOKUP($A4&"dec";
{ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!$B$3&Sheet1!$C$6)
\Candidate_View!$E$6};2;0);"")
```

So this orders cells in GM to either give out what is in Sheet 1 or be left blank. And when I change the email adress in Sheet 1, another cell in GM will have input, and the rest will be blank.

In GN I thought about doing a Query, but I do not think it will work. The problem is, there are formulas that can tell you in which cells a certain "text" is but no formulas (that I know of) act only if a certain "text" is in a cell (like a trigger).

This is what I dream of:

```
  Moment 1:                                       Moment 2:

 |A                     |GM       |GN       |    |A|GM  |GN       |
 |----------------------|---------|---------|    |-|----|---------|
4|email@email.com       |         |UNCERTAIN|    | |PASS|PASS     |
5|haha@test.com         |         |UNCERTAIN|    | |    |UNCERTAIN|
6|rainbowlover@email.com|UNCERTAIN|UNCERTAIN|    | |    |UNCERTAIN|
7|aaaa@bbbb.ccc         |         |PASS     |    | |    |PASS     |
8|help@me.please        |         |PASS     |    | |    |PASS     |
```

Also tried out doing it in apps script but did not get that far...

```
function decisions(){
 var source="GM4:GM";
 var destination="GN4:GN";
 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(source).findAll["UNCERTAIN","PASS",
"REJECT",false] //so this is basically which cells I want to copy

  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(source).
  copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(destination) // and this 
is where I want them copied. How do I combine the two?
}
```

Hope what I'm trying to do is a bit clearer now..
Only to assure you again. I am trying to figure out on my own as well, just thought someone might have a good idea or a clue for me. No need to solve the whole thing. I have started with google sheets about a months, so I am still looking for hours to find something like query...

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, from `I am looking for a way to tell cells GN4:GN to only copy from cells in GM4:GM if they contain "PASS", "UNCERTAIN", or "REJECT"; if not, nothing should be done. It is important that if the cells in GN4:GN contain something else than the listed words, GM4:GM stay the same as before.`, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: This sounds to me like your trying to tell us as little as possible in order to get us to do something that you don't know how nor want to learn how to do yourself but there's probably more to it than you're saying.  I don't like to do things in the dark.  I'm voting to close this until you provide more information.

Comment: @Tanaike: Hey I put a sample input output to clarify. Am I making sense now?

Comment: @Cooper: That's fine I get it. I am willing to learn though. Maybe have another look? I put some more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `IF` function of Google Sheets:

```
=if(B3="reject", "reject", if(B3="uncertain", "uncertain", if(B3="pass", "pass", B3)))
```

Note that this formula is not case sensitive. So "Pass", "PASS", "pAss" or any other variation outputs the specified string, which is "pass" in this case.

Please see the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18aMCIPgrMeyFiuxLbE4s2h7v7YCkbRjhGpS9anQh1-0/edit#gid=0

If you want to modify cell values through Google Apps Script, you should use `.setFormula()` ([See the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula))

Comment: Thank you. The problem is: If the source cell is empty, the output cell will say empty, it should stay what it was before though.

Comment: @mojo I have updated the formula. Can you please check the document again?

Comment: Thank you. I don't think an IF formula will help though because if there is nothing in a source cell, the formular will give an ERROR; it should not do anything though, to make sure that the data is save.

Comment: What do you mean? The formula handles the case that there is no value in the cell. Did you actually check the example sheet?There are cells without value and it doesn't return any error

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the ,B3 at the end so it did not work in my sheet. You solved it. Thank you!